# multithreading asynchronous server client

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, server

I'm trying to upgrade a server / client (player) application on windows forms to deal with a multiplayer environment (4 players) as part of an assignment for my coding course, using tcplistener and tcpclient. I'm relatively new to coding, especially on such complex topics. I hope I'm going on the right track for this.

I've been researching extensively lately so, by now, I think I have a good idea on the meaning and differences of threading and asynchronous execution. My main problem is on implementing it and getting it to work.

So, I started by working on the code provided on class (with some minor changes), it's working on a server player scenario (server side):

```
    void StartServer()
    {
        IPAddress ipaddr = IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress());
        int nport = 23000;

        mTcpListener = new TcpListener(ipaddr, nport);
        mTcpListener.Start();

        txtMessages.Text += "Server Listening on IP: " + ipaddr + " Port: " + nport + Environment.NewLine;
        mTcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServerAcceptClient, mTcpListener);
    }  

    void ServerAcceptClient(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        TcpListener tcpl = (TcpListener)iar.AsyncState;
        mTcpClient = tcpl.EndAcceptTcpClient(iar);

        txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtMessages.Text += "Player accepted..." + Environment.NewLine;
        });

        mRx = new byte[1460];
        mTcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(mRx, 0, mRx.Length, ServerRead, mTcpClient);
    }

    void ServerRead(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        TcpClient tcpc = (TcpClient)iar.AsyncState;
        int nReadBytes = 0;
        string strRecv = null;
        nReadBytes = tcpc.GetStream().EndRead(iar);
        if (nReadBytes == 0)
        {
            txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtMessages.Text += $"Player disconnected...{Environment.NewLine}";
                return;
            });
        }
        strRecv = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mRx, 0, nReadBytes);

        //Game classes and/or methods
        txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtMessages.Text += strRecv + Environment.NewLine;
        });
        mRx = new byte[1024];

        mTcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(mRx, 0, mRx.Length, ServerRead, mTcpClient);
    }
```

I've been through some tutorials, build some examples found on the web, I'm now able to get a simple synchronous multithreaded chat for the console. I tried to export those ideas on to windows forms, maybe in a bit naïvely way:

```
mTcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServerThreaded, mTcpListener);
```

and:

```
        void ServerThreaded(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        mTcpListener = (TcpListener)iar.AsyncState;

        int nplayer = 1;
        while (nplayer <= 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming client connections...");
            //mTcpClient = mTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //mTcpClient = mTcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(iar);
            TcpClient player = mTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Accepted new client connection...");
            Thread t = new Thread(() => ServerAcceptClient(iar));
            t.Start();
            nplayer++;
        }
    }
```

Obviously it's not working... last exception I was getting on a regular basis were of the form System.InvalidOperationException: "EndAccept can only be called once for each asynchronous operation".

Am I going with this tottaly on the wrong way? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/creating-a-web-server-in-c/
It is an example of simple HTTP server with implementation of multiple threads by means of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method.